# How to process different parts of the same video in parallel?

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently trying to process a video in parallel. However I haven't been able to use just one video capture and then let each process access the part that correspond to. I wonder if there is a way to create chunks of video so I don't have to allocate the whole video on each process. I wish to do something like this:

```
def process(video, init_frame, end_frame): 
    video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,init_frame*1000.0/FPS) 
    for i in range(init_frame,end_frame) 
        im, t = video.read()
        #do something with the frame im

def main(file,number_process,fragment_size):

   video = cv2.VideoCapture(file)

   for i  in range(number_process):
      start = int(i*fragment_size)
      end = int(start+fragment_size)
      if i == number_models-1:
          end = int(num_frames)
      processes[i] = mp.Process(target=process,args=(video,start,end)
```

However, this won't work because the reader locks the video in one specific frame, so only one of the process will be able to advance trough the video. I wonder if there is any other way to achieve something similar? any recommendation very welcome.

Comment: Why don't you capture a frame, pass it to a thread and then capture the next one, and pass it to the second thread?

Comment: I am trying to send the batch of images into a dl model for prediction. However I think your idea might work if I prepare the first batch send it to the first thread... etc etc.  Any light on the threading process very appreciated.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to  prepare the first batch, pass it through the network, during the forward pass prepare the next batch.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your last comment.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, so Im trying to think how to do what you said but in multiple threads.